# Hessian on Riemannian product manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M_1,g_1) \times (M_2,g_2)$ be a Riemannian product-manifold, and let $f:(M_1 \times M_2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ a positive scalar function on the product manifold.

If $H^f$ is the Hessian of the fuction $f$ on the product manifold, can it be written as $H^f=H_1^f +H_2^f$?

(where with $H_1^f$ and $H_2^f$, I mean the Hessian of $f$ on $(M_1, g_1)$ and $(M_2, g_2)$ respecrively).

Comment: Depending on what you mean by $+$, it seems so.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - thank you for your answer, I mean the sum

Comment: But these are quadratic forms on the respective tangent spaces, so there should officially be pullbacks to the product manifold.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - Thank you again! correctly how should I write it?

Comment: Oh, I take it back. I thought your $f$ was a product function. If it's a general function, you're missing the "off-diagonal" parts of the Hessian form. If $f=f_1+f_2$, where each is a function on its individual manifold, then $\text{Hess} f = \pi_1^*\text{Hess}(f_1) + \pi_2^*\text{Hess}(f_2)$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - if, for example,  $\pi_1^* \Delta(f_1)=0$ is the Laplacian it means that $f_1$ is harmonic?

Comment: This is a totally different question? What's the $\pi$ doing there? There are also different sign conventions on the Laplacian.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - sorry, I mean if the contraction of $\pi_1^*Hess(f_1)$ is equal to $0$

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - How can I write the contraction of $Hess(f)=\pi_1^*Hess(f_1)+\pi_2^*Hess(f_2)$?

Comment: Yes, again, not sure about sign conventions, but I would write it as the sum of the Laplacians. Now that it's a scalar-valued function I wouldn't bother with pullbacks. Maybe $\Delta_1(f_1) + \Delta_2(f_2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - sorry last thing, if I have $grad(f)$ it is the same as $Hess(f)$, i.e., $grad(f)=\pi_1^*grad(f_1)+\pi_2^*grad(f_2)$, Am I right?

Comment: No, this doesn't make sense. $\text{grad}(f)$ is a tangent vector, so you can't pull it back. But the tangent space of the product manifold is the product of the tangent spaces, so you should have $\text{grad}(f) = \big(\text{grad}(f_1),\text{grad}(f_2)\big)$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - thank you very much! With $(grad(f_1),grad(f_2))$ do you mean scalar product ? Respect which metric?

Comment: Stop and think.